# Fast Answers on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, microsoft

I'm used to programming in a classroom environment where people are able to answer questions quickly, if I get stuck. I'm preparing to do my first solo project over the summer. Is there any way to guarantee quick responses (on this site or any other) during rapid development phases?

Comment: you will remember the answers better if you put some work into finding the answers yourself first

Comment: No, there is no way to **guarantee** quick responses.  Better questions will, in general, result in better and quicker answers.

Comment: This depends. If you write in [tag:C#], the busiest tag on SO, then you probably receive a quick answer. If you write in Intercal, you have to wait. Probably.

Comment: The longer you spend making your question and title good, enjoyable to read and easily comprehensible the quicker the responses will be as more people will look at it and they won't have to ask for clarification.

Comment: Ay carumba. I foresee you will become a powerful jedi knight. Or question banned. One or the other. Hard to see, the future is.

Comment: oh well, second failed attempt at tumbleweed badge

Comment: Actually, scratch that. The future is easy to see. This website has gamification, but it is not a game. [Do not ask junk questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943227/dont-respond-to-this-please) just to earn badges.

Comment: @user414076 Nope; I'm feeling pretty strong about question banned given his current record.

Comment: It's very good you like working in a team. StackOverflow will help you if you find a really tough problem to you. People here are usually quick in my experience.

Comment: If you need guarantees, hire a consultant.

Answer (score 7):

No, there isn't a "way to guarantee quick responses". People on Stack Overflow are volunteers and you can't expect them to be at your beck and call.

You should learn to be self reliant - part of that is to learn how to experiment with code and such.